# Expresión regular y Javascript para texto desperdigado entre etiquetas HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex

he de usar Javascript y estoy intentando seleccionar un texto que, inicialmente, cumple este patrón:

```
{{texto|numero::texto|numero::texto|numero}}
```

Esto sería muy sencillo de capturar con una expresión regular, el problema es que tengo una base de datos bastante amplia en el que este texto está entremezclado con html, de forma que pasan cosas como esta:

```
{{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">alḡára,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em;">ḡārah.</em>::Origen etimológico}} continuaría habiendo texto durante largo tiempo {{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">alḡilála,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">ḡalālah</em><span>&nbsp;</span>o<span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">ḡilālah</em><span>&nbsp;</span>'túnica'.::Origen etimológico}}</p>
```

Si extraemos el texto del párrafo anterior, nos quedaría:

```
{{c1::Del ár. hisp. alḡára, y este del ár. clás. ḡārah.::Origen etimológico}}
```

Que, como digo, sería muy fácil de seleccionar, sin embargo, con el código por medio veo inviable capturar. Lo único que se me ocurre que pueda hacerse, de forma casi desesperada, es alguna forma de que se aplique el html para que se pueda trabajar sobre el texto sin más. No tengo más ideas. Sé que normalmente se suelen pedir ejemplos de que se ha estado trabajando por una solución pero no quiero inhundar esto de terribles expresiones regulares que no cumplen lo que necesito. Además, al trabajar con Javascript, tengo menos opciones con las expresiones regulares que si lo hiciera con otro lenguaje.

En resumen, lo que necesito es poder capturar lo que va después de los primeros "::" y tras los siguientes "::" hasta antes de las "}}". Si fuese esta la frase:

```
{{probando::primero::segundo}}
```

Necesitaría poder extraer de ahí "primero" y "segundo".

Por dejar un pequeño ejemplo de las últimas expresiones regulares que he estado intentando (en vano):

```
{{[^\:\:]+\:\:([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9]*)(?:<[^>]*>?)*([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9]*)(?:<[^>]*>?)*\:\:([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9]*)(?:<[^>]*>?)*([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9]*)(?:<[^>]*>?)*}}
```

```
(?:{{[^\:]+\:\:)(([a-zA-ZñÑáāéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9&;\., ḡ]*)|(?:\<[^>]*\>?)*)+\:\:(([a-zA-ZñÑáāéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ0-9&;\., ḡ]*)|(?:\<[^>]*\>?)*)+}}
```

Comment: Se me olvidó decir que no puedo quitar el código HTML porque el formato que genera al texto es muy importante. Si no fuese así, sencillamente primero borraría todo el código HTML y después usaría la expresión regular sencilla que capturaría el formato básico

Comment: ¿Podemos asumir que no hay `::` ni `}}` dentro de los tags html? ¿Y es completamente necesario validar que sean esos caracteres dentro de cada grupo? Porque conviene hacerlo más genérico

Comment: El texto incluye saltos de línea y un `</p>` al final ¿Las cadenas reales incluyen esto?

Comment: No respondí cuando tocaba, no vi los comentarios aquí. @Mariano efectivamente no hay :: no }} dentro de los tags y Ruben las cadenas reales sí incluyen eso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de resolverlo es olvidarse de los tags HTML, y hacer que coincida hasta la primera ocurrencia de los `::` y `}}` respectivamente.

**No goloso**. Es decir, hacemos que coincida con *cualquier* caracter, los menos posibles, hasta que encuentre un separador:

```
/\{\{.*?::(.*?)::(.*?)}}/g
```

- El `?` al final del `.*` hace que el cuantificador sea no goloso, que consuma *lo menos posible* antes de coincidir. Por eso, primero empieza intentando con 0, luego con 1, etc. (en vez intentar de más a menos, que es el comportamiento predeterminado).

**Multilínea**. Un punto coincide con cualquier caracter excepto los saltos de línea. Para que también coincida con un texto que se expande en más de una línea, tenemos que reemplazar los puntos por `[\s\S]` (un espacio o un no espacio -o sea, todos).

```
/\{\{[\s\S]*?::([\s\S]*?)::([\s\S]*?)}}/g
```

Demo:

```js
let texto = `{{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">alḡára,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em;">ḡārah.</em>::Origen etimológico}} continuaría habiendo texto durante largo tiempo {{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">alḡilála,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">ḡalālah</em><span>&nbsp;</span>o<span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:
0.015em;">ḡilālah</em><span>&nbsp;</span>'túnica'.::Origen etimológico}}</p>`,
    resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');


let regex = /\{\{[\s\S]*?::([\s\S]*?)::([\s\S]*?)}}/g,
    match,
    n = 0;
    
while (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
    resultado.innerText += 'TOKEN: ' + (++n) + '\n'
                         + 'PRIMERO: ' + match[1] + '\n'
                         + 'SEGUNDO: ' + match[2] + '\n\n';
}
```

```html
Resultado:
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

> Se asume (para simplificar la expresión):
>
> - que no hay `{{`, `::` ni `}}` *dentro* de un tag (que no debería considerarse como separador).
> - que no hay tags entre los 2 caracteres de un separador. Ejemplo: `:<b>:</b>` no lo considera un separador.
> - que no hay construcciones "*incompletas*", como podría ser `{{in::com::ple{{uno::dos::tres}}`
> - que los tokens tienen 3 elementos. Si hubiese uno más, lo tomaría como parte del tercero. Ej: `{{uno::dos::tres::tres B}}`.

---

**Obtener 2 o 3 elementos**. Para que coincida con `{{uno::dos}}` y al mismo tiempo con `{{uno::dos::tres}}`, hacemos que toda la última parte del regex sea opcional, encerrándola en un grupo `(?:`…`)?` donde el cuantificador `?` hace que sea opcional (repetido 0 o 1 vez).

```
/\{\{[\s\S]*?::([\s\S]*?)(?:::([\s\S]*?))?}}/g
```

Demo:

```js
let texto = `{{uno::dos}} {{uno::dos::tres}}`;


let regex = /\{\{[\s\S]*?::([\s\S]*?)(?:::([\s\S]*?))?}}/g,
    match,
    n = 0;
    
while (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
    console.log('TOKEN', (++n), 'DOS:', match[1], 'TRES:', match[2]);
}
```

**O reemplazar según el caso**. Si queremos reemplazar por cosas diferentes, según si hay 2 o 3 elementos, podemos llamar a una función que evalúe el texto a reemplazar... O incluso mostrar valores diferentes según el número de reemplazo:

Demo:

```js
let texto = "El primero no se muestra, {{c1::Cantar::Es secreto}}, el segundo si: {{c1::Cantar::Es secreto}} ";


let regex = /\{\{[\s\S]*?::([\s\S]*?)(?:::([\s\S]*?))?}}/g,
    resultado,
    n = 0;
    
resultado = texto.replace(
    regex,
    function (match, grupo1, grupo2) {
        n++;
        if (grupo2) { //tiene 3 elementos?
            if (n == 1) { //es el primer reemplazo
                return grupo2;
            } else {
                return grupo1;
            }
        } else { //tiene 2 elementos
            if (n == 1) { //es el primer reemplazo
                return '[...]';
            } else {
                return grupo1;
            }
        }
    }
);

console.log('TEXTO:',texto);
console.log('RESULTADO',resultado);
```

---

Nota sobre la eficiencia: en los ejemplos anteriores, se intentó mostrar la solución más sencilla pero, como `[\s\S]*?` también coincide con `::`, sería muchísimo más eficiente excluirlo (e incluso evitar un posible [backtracking catastrófico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/127)). Para eso, se deberían reemplazar los `[\s\S]*?` por:

```
[^:}]*(?:(?:}(?!})|:(?!:))[^:}]*)*
```

Comment: Llevo horas probando la solución que me dijiste que, como dije, funciona, sin embargo tengo conflicto al tratar de seleccionar una estructura tipo: {{uno::dos}} y a la vez una del tipo: {{uno::dos::tres}} Incluso aunque lo haga por separado, tratando de seleccionar primero una que excluya a la otra, no lo consigo, siempre se selecciona la contraria. Espero haberme explicado bien. Lo único que se me ocurre es un lookbehind del que carece javascript. Espero podáis ayudarme... de nuevo.

Comment: @Pip Editado con esa opción al final... Chrome ahora soporta lookbehinds, aunque no funcionaría en la mayoría de los navegadores, pero no son la solución en este caso (y rara vez suelen ser la solución -por lo general son más un problema :-)

Comment: Creo que debo de estar muy saturado (o falto de conocimientos) porque no se me ocurrió que la parte que se excluye del grupo tuviera dentro un grupo que sí se incluye. Pero, debido a que son situaciones diferentes las de {{uno::dos}} y {{uno::dos::tres}} porque si lo hago todo a la vez no sabré bien con qué estaré haciendo la sustitución, he de encontrar una exreg que seleccione uno y no el otro para hacer el replace sabiendo lo que cambio y después seleccionar el contrario. Pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, selecciono el contrario también. Intentaré continuar a partir de tu solución. Gracias!

Comment: No exactamente. Hay una pequeña lógica, si estamos ante un {{uno::dos}} en unas ocasiones haré un replace por sencillamente "[...]" y en otras por "$1", mientras que si se trata de un {{uno::dos::tres}}, sustituiré por "$2" y análogamente a lo dicho antes, por "$1" como en el anterior caso. Digamos que ahí estaría la diferencia, que {{uno::dos}} sería sustituido por la string "[...]" y {{uno::dos::tres}} por "$2", y si lo hago en un solo replace creo que no puedo saber dónde estoy sustituyendo si la regex vale para todos los casos. Por eso la buscaba por separado. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Creo que eso no se ajusta a lo que necesito (o no alcanzo a comprenderlo bien). Para los casos en que encuentre {{uno::dos}} la sustitución que necesito realizar podrá ser "[...]" o "$1" y para el caso de {{uno:.dos::tres}} la sustitución será "$2" o "$1".
Si no es la regex la que determina si nos hallamos ante {{uno::dos}} o {{uno::dos::tres}}, ¿Es capaz de discriminar eso la función que has planteado? Por eso yo buscaba una regex para detectar {{uno::dos}} y otra para {{uno::dos::tres}} que, al menos una de las dos, fuese excluyente de la otra, para tras la sustitución, usar la contraria

Comment: Para el caso de {{uno::dos}}, una cadena real podría ser {{c1::Cantar}} y la salida será "[...]" en un caso y "Cantar" ($1) en el otro. Porque primero ocultaré el valor y luego lo mostraré, en dos situaciones diferentes. Con {{uno::dos::tres}} sucederá algo similar, una cadena real sería: {{c1::Cantar::Es secreto}} donde en el primer caso mostraré "Es secreto" ($2) y en el segundo "Cantar" ($1)

Comment: @Pip ahora entiendo... Y hay un solo tipo de valor por texto? Es decir, el primer elemento siempre oculto y el segundo siempre se muestra?....  O hay más de 1 para cada entrada, y hay que verificar que coincida `Cantar`, que sólo se oculte la segunda ocurrencia de `Cantar`?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que el primer elemento es irrelevante, es decir, en el caso de {{c1::Cantar}} me refiero al "c1", cuando se trata de {{c1::Cantar}} lo mostraré oculto con "[...]" o lo enseñaré con "Cantar" usando $1. No hay más. Y con el caso de {{c1::Cantar::Es secreto}} sucede lo mismo. Por eso mi solución pasaba por hallar una regex que me permita sustituir todos los del primer tipo sin afectar a los del segundo o viceversa. El sustituirlos por una cosa u otra era lo de menos una vez tenía seleccionado sus elementos, cosa a lo que ya me ayudaste porque yo no lo conseguí por mí mismo

Comment: @Pip hecho... En el último ejemplo va cambiando según el número de sustitución

Comment: Creo que el chat hubiese sido una gran solución, ¡Lástima no tener el nivel! Yo recibiré una cadena variable pero que puede contener muchas de esas estructuras que hemos estado viendo. Pongamos que 10 de un tipo y 15 del otro y mezcladas en orden. La primera vez voy a mostrar en ambos casos la respuesta oculta y a la segunda, ya muestro el contenido que se desea ver, es decir, la primera vez muestro "[...]" o "Es secreto" y posteriormente (para todos los casos) mostraré "Cantar" (o $1). Era por explicar más concretamente pero, si con lo que me has puesto funciona, me queda intentar entenderlo

Comment: @Pip entiendo... Y creo que el ejemplo se puede adaptar fácil... Pero hace falta un buen ejemplo de texto para revisar (o varios ejemplos)... Y creo que ya se está haciendo difícil en comentarios... Quizás conviene que publiques una nueva pregunta, si te da la opción de poner tu código y los ejemplos bien formateados

Comment: No entiendo la función que tiene "match" en la funcion. Esto ya debido a mis precarios conocimientos. No estoy acostumbrado a declarar una función dentro de un argumento, aunque veo que es muy práctico. Y, por lo demás, tampoco entiendo el valor que tiene grupo1 o grupo2. Edito, entiendo que los argumentos de la función se corresponden con el match completo, el $1 y el $2

Comment: @Pip match va a contener siempre todo el texto que coincidió con la expresión regular, grupo1 lo que coincidió con el primer par de paréntesis, y grupo2 con los segundos... Los nombres los definí yo al declarar la función, se puede usar cualquier nombre de variable

Comment: Comprendo. No sabía que podía usarse así. Te agradezco mucho la ayuda Mariano. Es muy tarde aquí, casi hora de amanecer. Mañana por la mañana intentaré solucionarlo por mí mismo para evitar tener que pedir más ayuda, que bastante me has ayudado ya y a ver si así asimilo todo esto y lo aprendo. Un millón de gracias Mariano

Comment: Mariano, @Pip, recordad borrar los comentarios obsoletos y asi dejar *limpia* la publicacion ^^  si necesitais sala de chat avisad :D

Comment: Ah, ni me di cuenta de que no tenia rep para ello ... :/  tienes la sala aun creada? voy a intentar a ver si puedo hacerle "hablar"

Answer (score 2):

NOTA: Esta respuesta corresponde a la [versión inicial de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/142312/1).

> En resumen, lo que necesito es poder capturar lo que va después de los
>   primeros "::" y tras los siguientes "::" hasta antes de las "}}". Si
>   fuese esta la frase:
>
> {{probando::primero::segundo}} Necesitaría poder extraer de ahí
>   "primero" y "segundo".

Lo siguiente extrae primero (primera sección) y segundo (segunda sección) y lo imprime en la consola un array con cada elemento como miembro.

```js
var texto1 = '{{probando::primero::segundo}}';
var re = /:{2}(.*)}{2}/;
var resultado = texto1.match(re);
console.info(resultado[1].split('::'));
```

Lo siguiente extrae las cadenas de la primera y segunda sección de la cadena incluida como ejemplo por el OP y lo imprime al documento HTML. Para facilitar la identificación de cada parte se incluye como prefijo "Primera parte" y "Segunda parte" ambos en negritas.

```js
var texto1 = '{{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em;">alḡára,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em;">ḡārah.</em>::Origen etimológico}}';
var re = /:{2}(.*)}{2}/;
var resultado = texto1.match(re);
var resultado1 = resultado[1].split('::');
document.write('<b>Primera parte:</b> ' + resultado1[0] + '<br/>'+ '<b>Segunda parte:</b> ' + resultado1[1]);
```

Comment: He de pedir disculpas por no haber aclarado inicialmente que el texto en el que he de buscar, es un texto extenso que incluye varias ocurrencias de estructuras análogas a la que he puesto, por lo que con la regexp que me ha facilitado falla. No lo puse al pegar el texto porque me pareció extensísimo y ahora veo que la respuesta me limita los caracteres.

A mí me sucedió algo similar. Tengo el problema de no saber cómo hacer con una regexp que seleccione todo hasta que no encuentre dos veces la aparición de los "::", puesto que si encuentra un solo ":" se detiene.

De nuevo, disculpas.

Comment: He editado el párrafo sobre el que se trabaja. Al tener que encontrar varias ocurrencias, con la regexp que me facilitó, selecciona más allá de la última llave (puesto que vuelve a encontrar nuevas llaves que cierran más adelante). Llevo un largo día probando distintas combinaciones porque no encuentro manera de seleccionar esa estructura con varias ocurrencias de la misma y lo único que se me viene a la cabeza es seleccionar todo lo que no sean dos ":" seguidos, pero eso no parece posible. Tampoco me funciona el positive lookahead "?=" me ocurre lo mismo, selecciona de la primera a la última

Comment: El `.*` que usaste consume cualquier cantidad de caracteres, incluida otra ocurrencia del patrón, haciendo que falle en esos casos

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sin utilizar expresiones regulares. En su lugar se divide la cadena en partes tomando `::` como el separador y se descarta la subcadena  a partir de `}}` en caso de que este se incluya. Para fines de mostrar los elementos se agregar como texto de un `<p>` y se numera cada uno.

```js
var texto1 = '{{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:0.015em;">alḡára,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em;">ḡārah.</em>::Origen etimológico}} continuaría habiendo texto durante largo tiempo {{c1::Del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe hispánico">ár. hisp.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:0.015em;">alḡilála,</em><span>&nbsp;</span>y este del<span>&nbsp;</span><abbr style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; color: inherit; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing: 0.015em; cursor: pointer;" title="árabe clásico">ár. clás.</abbr><span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:0.015em;">ḡalālah</em><span>&nbsp;</span>o<span>&nbsp;</span><em style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-style: italic; font-variant: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: initial; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232) !important; letter-spacing:0.015em;">ḡilālah</em><span>&nbsp;</span>\'túnica\'.::Origen etimológico}}';

var resultado = texto1.split('::');
var element = document.getElementById('salida');
for (var i in resultado) {
  if( i == 0) continue;
  var l = resultado[i].indexOf('}}');
  element.innerHTML += '<p>'+ i +': ' + resultado[i].substring(0,(l>0)?l:resultado[i].length) + '</p>'; 
}
```

```html
<div id="salida"></div>
```

Comment: Lamento ser el aguafiestas, pero con preguntas de regex no lo puedo evitar... `::ej{{uno::dos::tres}}`

Comment: @mariano Ese patrón no está incluído en la pregunta :)

Comment: @Mariano: Una parte de mi comentario fue desafortunado. Lo siento. En lo que respecta a los supuestos, me parece que sí podemos asumir que el caso expuesto es representativo de las cadenas de las cuáles se hará la extracción porque a final de cuentas lo que importa son los conceptos más que la robustez de la solución sin embargo una respuesta que incluya una solución más robusta que otra definitivamente es mejor. En lo particular prefiero esperar a que el OP responda los comentarios a la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos. La solución de Mariano me ha funcionado (incluso me ha sido muy sencillo adaptarla al caso de que también tenga que seleccionar la estructura {{algo::algo}}, aunque lo más importante es lo que he aprendido gracias a vosotros. ¡Me habéis ayudado muchísimo! Ahora continuaré reflexionando si es viable eliminar de la selección todo rastro de HTML porque todo esto tiene como finalidad hacer una sustitución de {{uno::dos::tres}} por "dos" o "tres" según la circunstancia, pero siempre utilizando los $1 y compañía de regexp para no tocar el resto. ¡¡Mil gracias a ambos!!

Comment: @Mariano ^^^^^^