# Regex para hallar la raíz (lexema) de las palabras

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta es una duda directamente relacionada con las expresiones regulares y mi problema parte de las limitaciones que tiene JavaScript con ellas, o mi desconocimiento sobre cómo suplir estas con las herramientas que las regex tienen en JavaScript, ya que sin esas limitaciones he conseguido que funcione y con ellas no.

Mi objetivo es el siguiente. Recibo una palabra y trato de extraer algo aproximado (exacto es imposible, especialmente cuando se trata de verbos irregulares conjugados) a la raíz de la palabra. Para ello uso esta regex:

```
([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+(?<=[bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvxyz])(?=[aeiouáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+))([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+)
```

Aquí podéis observar que, aunque no sé bien si es completamente necesario, utilizo lookbehind en la primera parte de la regex. Como digo, obtener la raíz de la palabra es algo ambiguo, así que utilicé esta regex por probar una opción que sí me funcionó para mi propósito (sin embargo no puedo usarlo en JavaScript porque ya he comprobado que me da error). El funcionamiento de la regex (o al menos el resultado que me ofrece) es seleccionar la última parte de la palabra:

- Si acaba en vocal, seleccionará todas las vocales que haya hasta que encuentre una consonante (que no seleccionará).
- Si acaba en consonante, seleccionará todas las vocales, hasta que encuentre otra consonante (que no la seleccionará).

Ahora mi duda es, ¿Es posible conseguir este comportamiento sin ese positive lookbehind que he usado?

Aquí dejo una muestra de su comportamiento con un grupo de palabras, donde la idea es conseguir lo más aproximado a separar el lexema y el morfema de las palabras.

```js
let palabras = "blanco<br>taciturno<br>marital<br>cantar<br>extraer<br>turgentes<br>tropelía<br>ágave<br>panadero<br>panaderías";

let regex = /([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+(?<=[bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvxyz])(?=[aeiouáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+))([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+)/g;

let resultado = palabras.replace(regex,"$1");

document.getElementById("palabras").innerHTML = "<b>ORIGINAL</b><br><br>" + palabras;

document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "<b>RESULTADO</b><br><br>" + resultado;
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td id="palabras" align="right" style="border-style:solid;border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;padding:0px 5px 0px 0px"></td>
    <td id="resultado" align="left" style="border-style:solid;border-width:0px 0px 0px 1px;padding:0px 0px 0px 5px""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Uso esta regex [...] que sí me funcionó para mi propósito
>
> ```
> ([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+(?<=[bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvxyz])(?=[aeiouáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+))([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+)
> ```

Esta expresión lo que está haciendo es seleccionar 2 partes de una palabra, separando después de la última consonante que esté seguida por una vocal. Entonces, sin lookbehinds:

```
/([a-zñáéíóúü]*[b-df-hj-nñp-tv-z])([aeiouáéíóúü][a-zñáéíóúü]*)/igu
//             +----------------+  +-----------+
//                      |               |
//                      |               +---> seguida de una vocal
//                      |
//                      +---> La última consonante...
```

- El primer grupo toma todas las letras desde el inicio (el cuantificador `*` va a consumir cuantas más pueda) y *fuerza* que coincida con una consonante.
- El segundo grupo *fuerza* que coincida con una vocal, y consume el resto de las letras.

En tu ejemplo:

```js
let palabras = "blanco<br>taciturno<br>marital<br>cantar<br>extraer<br>turgentes<br>tropelía<br>ágave<br>panadero<br>panaderías";

let regex = /([a-zñáéíóúü]*[b-df-hj-nñp-tv-z])([aeiouáéíóúü][a-zñáéíóúü]*)/igu,
    resultado = palabras.replace(regex,"$1 - $2");

document.getElementById("palabras").innerHTML = "<b>ORIGINAL</b><br><br>" + palabras;
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "<b>RESULTADO</b><br><br>" + resultado;
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td id="palabras" align="right" style="border-style:solid;border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;padding:0px 5px 0px 0px"></td>
    <td id="resultado" align="left" style="border-style:solid;border-width:0px 0px 0px 1px;padding:0px 0px 0px 5px""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

> utilizo lookbehind [..] no puedo usarlo en JavaScript

Las inspecciones hacia atrás (*lookbehinds*) fueron implementadas recientemente en Chrome 62+ (21/8/17) ([issue 4545](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545&desc=2#c20)) y en Opera 49+ ([status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5668726032564224)). Podrías utilizarla en estos navegadores, aunque todavía es demasiado temprano como para pensar en usarlos en una solución que sea compatible con la mayoría de los navegadores.

De hecho, tu ejemplo me funciona perfecto, sin dar errores (y dando los mismos resultados que el regex que usé arriba)... Pero la solución sencilla es más rápida (una inspección hacia atrás es de las construcciones menos eficientes en regex).

Comment: Es perfecta la solución. Cuando utilizo expresiones verbales como "seleccionar", lo hago producto del desconocimiento acerca del funcionamiento interno de regex. Mi intención en este caso era obtener lo más aproximado a la raíz de una palabra, por eso la primera solución que me das me parece más ajustada a lo que busco, porque esta última creo que se queda corta. Por ejemplo "cantar" en una conjugación sería "yo cant-o", y no me serviría si obtengo "canta-r", porque a partir de "canta" no puedo encontrar variaciones como "canté" o "canto" en otros textos. Infinitas gracias por tu ayuda Mariano

Comment: @Pip lo sé... yo también me tomo algunas libertades para describir el caso... El tema es que me confundieron un poco tus 2 puntos sobre lo que querías obtener, por eso quise cubrir otras posibilidades... Elimino la última parte de la respuesta, no creo que le sirva a nadie :-)

Comment: Por último, añadir que el mundo de las regex me parece fascinante y ver el dominio que tienes sobre ello me hace sentir una muy sana envidia. ¿Sería adecuado que te preguntase por aquí qué documentación, curso o material podría estudiar para comprender, desde su modo más interno, cómo funcionan y cómo usar perfectamente regex? Me encantaría manejarlas con tanta soltura como tú lo haces, me parece tremendamente útil. Un saludo y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @Pip puse los mejores recursos online que conozco en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info ... Si te animás a leer en inglés, el tutorial completo de http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html es lo mejor para                                                                                                         dominar todo lo importante... Te puede llevar algunos días (leyendo y releyendo), pero vale la pena.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano. Lamentablemente el inglés sí es una barrera para mí. Pero guardaré esa página para intentar ir a ella cuando reuna ánimos de enfrentarme al idioma. Edito. He visto que en las otras que hay dentro del primer enlace aquí en stackoverflow sí hay material en español. Empezaré por ello.

Comment: @Pip no conozco algo que se le iguale en español. Sin embargo, los 3 primeros links de https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info están en español... quizás leyendo un poco de eso, más [**las preguntas de SOes**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?sort=votes), y mucha práctica te deje en camino... Una respuesta mía que te recomiendo leer es [¿Cómo funciona el retroceso (Backtracking) en expresiones regulares?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/127) (no sé si es sencillo entenderla ahora o más adelante, pero es un punto importante en cómo funciona el motor de regex).