# Cómo puedo repetir un grupo de captura

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo varios strings con la siguiente estructura:

```
AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_15_17
AAAA_BBBB_1
AAAA_BBBB_15_17
```

Estoy tratando de buscar un regex que me capture los siguientes grupos:

```
GRUPO1: AAAA  GRUPO2: BBBB_CCCC GRUPO3: 1_15_17
GRUPO1: AAAA  GRUPO2: BBBB GRUPO3: 1
GRUPO1: AAAA  GRUPO2: BBBB GRUPO3: 15_17
```

He probado lo siguiente:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)_(\d+_?)+
```

Estoy teniendo problemas con el tercer grupo, pues parece que el siguiente `match`, sobrescribe al anterior utilizando el `+` para el grupo `(\d+_?)+`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)_(\d+_?)+/

const string = 'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_2'

const [fullMatch, ...groups] = string.match(regex)

console.log(groups)
```

En el ejemplo `1_2` solo me coge el `2`.

¿Cómo puedo capturar este último grupo completo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Una captura siempre se sobreescribe**. Así es como funcionan las expresiones regulares. Al repetir un grupo, siempre se sobreescribe la captura con la última coincidencia. Por ejemplo, algo como

```
/(\d)+/
```

siempre va a capturar el último dígito del entero.

**Cuidado con cuantificadores anidados**. También estás teniendo un problema en tu regex, que no es evidente ahora, pero puede traerte problemas en el futuro. Al usar:

```
[a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?
```

estás repitiendo consecutivamente 2 construcciones que coinciden con lo mismo. Como el `_` es opcional, el regex puede convertirse en `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+?`, y una construcción así es la receta perfecta para un [backtracking catastrófico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/127)!

Además, con esa misma construcción, estás exigiendo que tenga al menos 2 caracteres, por lo que no va a coincidir jamás con un texto como `A_B_1`.

**Solución: repetir dentro del grupo**. Para evitar esto, lo que hacemos es englobar a toda la parte opcional en un [grupo sin captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches), cuantificado con `?`. Es decir:

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)?)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aplicamos la misma lógica a la parte de dígitos (repetida con `*`).

Regex:

```
 /^([a-z]+)_([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)?)_(\d+(?:_\d+)*)$/i
```

Código:

```js
let pruebas = [
        'AAAA_BBBB_1',
        'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1',
        'AAAA_BBBB_1_2_3_4',
        'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_2_3',
        'A_B_1',
        'A_B_C_1_2',
        'A_B_C_D_1'
    ];

const regex = /^([a-z]+)_([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)?)_(\d+(?:_\d+)*)$/i;
let match;


for (let texto of pruebas) {
    console.log(texto);
    if (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
        console.log('Grupo 1:',match[1],'Grupo 2:',match[2],'Grupo 3:',match[3]);
    } else {
        console.log('no coincide!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

De manera similar a la forma en que atrapaste el segundo grupo, se puede hacer el tercero con la ayuda de los *non capturing groups*.

```
([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+(?:_\d+)*)
```

La máquina de estados quedaría algo así:

[image: máquina de estados del regex]

Cuando le pones los símbolos `?:` dentro de un grupo, le estas indicando que no te capture ese grupo, o dicho de una mejor manera que lo capture pero que no lo registre entre los grupos capturados.

Es importante notar que aunque pareciera que con la primera mitad del grupo 3 bastaría no es así, pues si tenemos más de una repetición el grupo solamente atrapará el final que concuerde y no todo el grupo de caracteres que deseamos.

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+(?:_\d+)*)/

const strings = [
        'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_15_17'
        ,'AAAA_BBBB_1'
        ,'AAAA_BBBB_15_17'
        ,'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_2'
    ]

strings.forEach(string => {
  const [fullMatch, ...groups] = string.match(regex)
  console.log(groups)
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me podrías decir qué utilizas para visualizar el regex en forma de diagrama? :)

Comment: Te dejo una lista de herramientas que podrían serte de utilidad, la que usé incluida: http://javapro.org/castellano/2018/03/04/herramientas-para-expresiones-regulares/