# Captura de un grupo sin captura o captura de grupo con captura

Tags: javascript, regex

Hoy contestando [una pregunta en este sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143095/como-puedo-repetir-un-grupo-de-captura/143099#143099) me hallé con una posible solución muy interesante, pues accidentalmente borré una parte de la solución y esa solución funcionó aunque no tenía sentido para mí.

Sin más preámbulos:

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+)/

const strings = [
        'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_15_17'
        ,'AAAA_BBBB_1'
        ,'AAAA_BBBB_15_17'
        ,'AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1_2'
    ]

strings.forEach(string => {
  const [fullMatch, ...groups] = string.match(regex)
  console.log(groups)
})
```

como verán, capturé un grupo sin captura mediante `((?:_\d+)+)`, y en el sitio regex101 me funciona para todos los lenguajes, que hasta este momento son:

- pcre (php)
- javascript
- python
- golang

Nota: viendo que no todo el mundo lee toda al información disponible, lo trascendente es que estoy obteniendo el comportamiento de

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+(?:_\d+)*)/
```

usando

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+)/
```

lo cual es extraño, debido a que si no hago la captura, el grupo atrapado es solo la última parte que concuerda:

```js
const regex = /(_\d+)+/g;
const str = `_1_2_3_4_5_6_7`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```

Desearía que alguien me explicara por qué funcionó usar una doble captura y que implicaciones (positivas o negativas) tiene atrapar un grupo sin captura así como lo hice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> capturé un grupo de no captura mediante `((?:_\d+)+)`, y en el sitio regex101 me funciona para todos los lenguajes que hasta este momento son

Y te va a funcionar en cualquier dialecto de regex.

- Todos excepto BREs, POSIX EREs u Oracle para ser exacto, ya que no soportan grupos sin captura: `(?:`…`)`.

---

> estoy obteniendo el comportamiento de
>
> ```
> /([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+(?:_\d+)*)/
> ```
>
> usando
>
> ```
> /([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+)/
> ```

De hecho, utilizar la primera forma sería un error, ya que estás repitiendo innecesariamente el `(?:_\d+)*` del final, que jamás va a coincidir con nada, porque la construcción anterior (`(?:_\d+)+`), ya consumió todos los que había, sin dejar nada para el último.

Se puede corroborar con un ejemplo, agregando un grupo más alrededor del último `(?:_\d+)*`.

```js
const texto = '_123_456_789_0',
      regex = /((?:_\d+)+((?:_\d+)*))/;
      [match, grupo1, grupo2] = regex.exec(texto);

console.log(`Grupo 1: "${grupo1}"`);
console.log(`El último '(?:_\d+)*' coincidió con: "${grupo2}"`);
```

---

> Desearía que alguien me explicara por qué funcionó usar una doble captura

No estás usando una doble captura. En `((?:_\d+)+)`, únicamente el grupo exterior es el que captura. Y justamente `(?:`…`)` es un [**grupo sin captura**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches).

Una estructura como `((?:_\d+)+)` es perfectamente normal y se usa frecuentemente. Pensalo de esta forma: es lo mismo que `(\d+)`, sólo que lo que se repiten en `((?:_\d+)+)` no son solamente dígitos sino guiones bajos seguidos de dígitos.

Anidar grupos (con o sin captura) es tan válido como, y prácticamente lo mismo que, utilizar bucles anidados en tu código... Tan simple como eso.

---

> qué implicaciones (positivas o negativas) tiene atrapar un grupo de no captura así como lo hice.

Ninguna. Ni positiva ni negativa. No hubieses logrado el mismo resultado sin anidar un grupo sin captura dentro de uno con captura de esa forma... De nuevo, es una estructura completamente normal.

De hecho, como regla general, siempre deberías usar grupos sin captura `(?:`…`)` cuando no necesites obtener el texto con el que coincidió. Un grupo sin captura no ocupa memoria innecesaria (ni en capturar el texto, ni en generar los índices de las posiciones inicial y final).

- Si te interesa entrar muchísimo más en detalle, un grupo sin captura es apenas más lento al compilar, pero más eficiente al ejecutar. Sin embargo, esta diferencia es despreciable, y se suele optar por preferir ahorrar memoria (está mejor visto desde el punto de vista de las buenas prácticas).

---

De yapa, una corrección más. Utilizar una estructura como:

```
([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)
```

es un error. Estás repitiendo consecutivamente 2 construcciones que coinciden con lo mismo. Como el `_` es opcional, el regex puede convertirse en `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+?`, y una construcción así es la receta perfecta para un [backtracking catastrófico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/127).

Este es un problema que no va a generar un error en los casos que estás viendo, pero con un regex un poco más complicado, textos más largos y una condición que no coincida, podría hacer que el navegador se congele sin devolver un resultado.

Veamos una prueba, no tan drástica, pero lo suficientemente evidente:

```js
const regex = /^([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+)$/,
      N = 1000,
      texto = 'X_'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            + '_1_2_ERROR';

//Tu regex
let a, b, resultado;

a = performance.now()
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    resultado = regex.exec(texto);
}
b = performance.now();

console.log('"([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)" Tardó:', (b - a), 'ms. en devolver:', resultado);


//Con un grupo sin captura anidado
const regexConGrupo = /^([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)?)((?:_\d+)+)$/;
a = performance.now()
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    resultado = regexConGrupo.exec(texto);
}
b = performance.now();

console.log('"([a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)?)" Tardó:', (b - a), 'ms. en devolver:', resultado);
```

Y esto, si fuese parte de un regex más complicado podría traerte serios problemas.

Además, al usar `([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)`, estás exigiendo que tenga al menos 2 caracteres, por lo que no coincidiría con algo como `A_B_1`.

Answer (score -1):

La verdad es que no tiene ninguna implicancia. Un grupo de no-captura sirve simplemente para agrupar una expresion por conveniencia, sin que el resultado sea retornado en un grupo, esto no significa que no pueda formar parte de otro grupo.

Considerando el siguiente ejemplo:

```
"cababaabc".match(/c(a|b)*c/).slice(1) // => ["b"]
```

No obtengo el grupo de `a`'s y `b`'s, sino un grupo que tal vez no me interese: la ultima `a` o ultima `b` de la expresion `a|b`

Si uso un grupo de no-captura:

```
"cababaabc".match(/c(?:a|b)*c/).slice(1) // => []
```

No obtengo ningun grupo.

Pero si me interesa saber la cadena completa entre ambas `c`, estoy obligado a poner un grupo, encerrando por completo la expresion de interes, incluyendo `*`:

```
"cababaabc".match(/c((?:a|b)*)c/).slice(1) // => ["ababaab"]
```

Obteniendo el grupo completo de `a`'s y `b`'s

### EDICION:

Si lo que te interesa es comparar tus 2 expresiones:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+(?:_\d+)*)/
```

y

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+?)((?:_\d+)+)/
```

Dejame decirte que son completamente equivalentes:

El ultimo grupo en ambas:

```
((?:_\d+)+(?:_\d+)*)
((?:_\d+)+)
```

Es lo mismo que:

```
((?:A)+(?:A)*)
((?:A)+)
```

Con `A = _\d+` y en la primera:

`(?:A)+(?:A)*` es equivalente a `A+A*` lo que sin lugar a dudas es lo mismo que `A+`

Notar que ni siquiera estas capturando el *mismo* grupo de no-captura, sino uno diferente:

`((?:A)+)` el cuantificador `+` lo hace una expresion diferente, incluso aunque fuese la misma expresion, no hay nada que impida capturar el mismo grupo:

`((A))` es tan valido como `((?:A))`

Comment: el problema radica en que se está lanzando una búsqueda con llamadas recursivas en el último patrón de manera implícita, la manera explícita es la fomra en que contesté en la pregunta relacionada. favor de probar la expresión regular antes de contestar ya que así no es de utilidad (y el botón de flecha hacia abajo sirve para las respuestas que no son de utilidad) .

Comment: la verdad es que no entiendo a que te refieres con lanzar busquedas con llamadas recursivas, todas las expresiones que pongo las pruebo.

Comment: ya te agregué un ejemplo al final con el uso de un grupo de captura únicamente para que veas por que lo que dices no es de utilidad

Comment: ¿Y por qué son equivalentes?

Comment: Son 2 expresiones con *resultados* equivalentes, `A+A*` va a hacer exactamente los mismos matchs que `A+`. Por cierto si quieres leer acerca del porque un grupo de captura repetido solo captura el ultimo match, entonces mira la especificacion: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-repeatmatcher-abstract-operation

Comment: Pues entonces volvemos a lo mismo, porque aunque la versión corta sea una versión optimizada no explicas por que se obtienen los mismos resultados que es lo que estoy preguntando.

Comment: "por qué funcionó usar una doble captura y que implicaciones (positivas o negativas) tiene atrapar un grupo de no captura así como lo hice"