# ¿Cómo puedo verificar en PHP si una URL no termina por el caracter / y agregárselo?

Tags: php, regex

Estoy guardando la cantidad de vistas de las URL de mi página en una base de datos. Las mismas son tomadas de Google Analytics.

En la tabla la columna que guarda la URL está declarada como única, y dicha columna es *case insensitive*.

El problema es que GA trata de forma distinta estas URL por ejemplo:

- `/Jn-12_20-33`
- `/Jn-12_20-33/`
- `/jn-12_20-33`
- `/jn-12_20-33/`

Dado que la columna es *case insensitive*, no se insertarán como repetidas las filas `/jn-12_20-33`  y `/Jn-12_20-33`. Pero las filas `/jn-12_20-33` y `/jn-12_20-33/` sí se insertarán como repetidas, cuando es la misma URL.

Lo que quisiera saber es **cómo determinar los casos en que la URL no termine por `/` y agregárselo.**

El código donde leo todas las URL y hago la inserción es el siguiente. El valor que quiero modificar sería `$row[0]`:

```
$sqlInsert="INSERT INTO google_analytics (url_path, ga_views, url_title) VALUES (:url_path,:ga_views,:url_title)";
$sqlRead="SELECT id FROM google_analytics WHERE url_path=:url_path";

$oPDO->beginTransaction();
try
{
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $arrRead=array('url_path'=>$row[0]);
        $id=$oPDO->single($sqlRead, $arrRead);
        if ($id==0){
            $arrInsert=array('url_path'=>$row[0], 'ga_views'=>$row[1], 'url_title'=>$row[2]);
            $oPDO->query($sqlInsert, $arrInsert);
        }else{
            echo "Existe: ".$id.PHP_EOL;                            
        }
    }

$oPDO->executeTransaction();
echo "Proceso OK";

}catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
    $oPDO->rollBack();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> cómo determinar los casos en que la URL no termine por `/` y agregárselo

La forma más sencilla es hacerlo sin regex:

```
if (substr($url, -1) != '/') {
    $url .= '/';
}
```

- O en una línea (que no me gusta): `rtrim($url,'/').'/'`.

Pero, ya que estás preguntando por una expresión regular:

```
$url = preg_replace( '~(?:[^/]|^)$~', '$0/', $url);
```

La expresión regular coincide con

- `(?:[^/]|^)` ::: Un caracter, cualquiera menos `/`; o el incio del string `^` (para strings vacíos).
- `$` ::: el fin del string.

Y lo reemplaza por `$0/`, el texto que coincidió recién, seguido de una barra.

Si además te interesa identificar cuándo fue reemplazado, [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) tiene el último parámetro opcional que te devuelve la cantidad de reemplazos que se hicieron:

```
$url = preg_replace( '~(?:[^/]|^)$~', '$0/', $url, 1, $count);
if ($count) {
    // ...
}
```

O, al revés, ver que coincida y negar el resultado:

```
if (!preg_match( '~/$~', $url)) {
    $url .= '/';
}
```

---

Alternativamente podrías usar

```
$url = preg_replace( '~(?<!/)$~', '/', $url);
```

Es una inspección hacia atrás negativa (*negative lookbehind*) para verificar que el fin del texto no esté precedido por `/`. Te puede resultar mejor a la vista.

¿La URL tiene parámetros o un fragmento? Hacemos que coincida con todo el texto desde el inicio, mientras no sea un `?` ni un `#`:

```
$url = preg_replace( '~^[^?#]*+(?<!/)\K~', '/', $url);
```

`[^?#]*+` coincide con todos los caracteres que puede, y el `+` extra hace que el cuantificador sea posesivo, que no pueda hacer [backtracking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/127) hacia una opción con menos caracteres. `\K` descarta la coincidencia hasta ese punto, permitiéndonos evitar usar `$0` en el reemplazo.

O lo mismo sin regex, con [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php):

```
$partes = parse_url($url);

$path = isset($partes['path']) ? $partes['path'] : '';
if (substr($path, -1) != '/') {
    $path .= '/';

    //esta parte está simplificada, podrías tener más partes, ver parse_url() en el manual
    $url = (isset($partes['scheme']) ? $partes['scheme'] . '://' : '') 
        . (isset($partes['host']) ? $partes['host'] : '')
        . $path
        . (isset($partes['query']) ? '?'.$partes['query'] : '')
        . (isset($partes['fragment']) ? '#'.$partes['fragment'] : '');
}
```

Son varias de las formas, hay más.

Comment: Funciona de cualquiera de las maneras. Muchísimas gracias.