# Error al validar nombres largos con expresión regular js

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

Tengo un formulario, todo funciona bien, la validación funciona, pero me di cuenta que mientras más largo es el nombre que valida, más tarda el navegador en responder. Llega un punto en el que tarda tanto que me da un error, osea, si ingreso "An dri son Sá" tarda un segundo en validarlo, mientras más cosas pongo, más tarda en validar, si pongo "Andrison Sánchez De La Cruz1" tarda mucho y luego me da el siguiente error [image: Error]

Este es el código que uso:

```
                <form action="">
                    <div class="mensaje">
                        <h3>Introduzca un correo válido</h3>
                    </div>
                    
                    <input class='validar' type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required minlength="2" placeholder="Nombre">
                    <input class='validar' type="email" name="email" id="email"  required placeholder="Correo">
                    <textarea class='validar' name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="5" minlength="20" maxlength="350" placeholder='Mensaje' required></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"  >
                </form>
```

JS:

```
  const exp_nombre=/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ _\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ _\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ _\u00f1\u00d1]+$/;

 function validar(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(!exp_nombre.test($inputs[0].value)){
    $error.textContent="Ingrese un nombre válido";
    $cont_ms.style.display='block';
    $inputs[0].classList.add("error");
}
```

}

Comment: Hola. Falta información: ¿qué evento llama a validar? ¿cuando y dónde es disparado? ¿Qué debe validar la exp?. Prueba con otra expresión regular **muy sencilla** sin otros cambios para descartar que el problema provenga de ella. Si se mantiene el problema la causa no sería la expresión. Si desaparece, la causa sería la expresión y debes trabajar sobre ella. **Siempre debes tratar de *cercar* el problema**

Comment: ¡madre mía qué regex! ¿qué estás intentando comprobar?¿por qué en el grupo de enmedio hay `\s*` y luego dentro de la siguiente expresión hay espacios, todo el grupo con *?

Comment: La regex valida que se introduzca un nombre válido, puede tener acentos y la letra ñ, no la hice yo, la busqué de internet

Comment: El evento que llama a validar es el submit del formulario, voy a probar con otra regex

Comment: Te expresion regular es muy ortodoxa, que es lo que quieres validar en los inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se soluciona eliminando todo lo duplicado que es redundante y hace caer en loops casi infinitos.

```
/^[a-zA-Z_\u00c0-\u00d1]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z_\u00c0-\u00d1]+)*$/
```

El problema en tu código es que las 3 partes `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ _\u00f1\u00d1]+`, `(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ _\u00f1\u00d1]*)*` y `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ _\u00f1\u00d1]+` tienen caracteres repetidos y se va a estar intentando que coincidan de muchas combinaciones diferentes sobre la misma porción de texto. Por eso es que cuanto más largo es el texto, más tiempo está tardando hasta llegar al error de *demasiada recursión*.

Este error se llama backtracking catastrófico. En [¿Cómo funciona el retroceso (Backtracking) en expresiones regulares?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/193460) se explica bien.